# Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 4.1 pixels on the bottom

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I am need to create to Material Widget per row, but when i create it i wanted to add padding when i do so for the column the yellow error appears with this error:

> Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 4.1 pixels on
> the bottom.
>
> Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 4.1 pixels on
> the bottom.
>
> Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 4.1 pixels on
> the bottom.
>
> > ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY
> > ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ The
> > following assertion was thrown during layout: A RenderFlex overflowed
> > by 0.200 pixels on the right. The relevant error-causing widget was:
> > Row
> > Row:file:///E:/work/nabaa_mobile-main/lib/ui/screens/home/widgets/bottom_home_page/home.dart:134:25
> > To inspect this widget in Flutter DevTools, visit:
> > http://127.0.0.1:9101/#/inspector?uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A56940%2FUjrL2FntShg%3D%2F&inspectorRef=inspector-1305
> > The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.horizontal. The
> > edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the
> > rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually
> > caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex. Consider
> > applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the
> > children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead
> > of being sized to their natural size. This is considered an error
> > condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be
> > seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space,
> > consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the
> > flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a
> > ListView. The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#164c6
> > relayoutBoundary=up1 OVERFLOWING: creator: Row ← Column ← Semantics ←
> > DefaultTextStyle ← AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ←
> > _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#020b0 ink renderer] ← NotificationListener ← CustomPaint ←
> > _ShapeBorderPaint ← PhysicalShape ← _MaterialInterior ← Material ← ⋯ parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use
> > size) constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=135.2, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
> > size: Size(135.2, 40.0) direction: horizontal mainAxisAlignment:
> > start mainAxisSize: max crossAxisAlignment: center textDirection: ltr
> > verticalDirection: down
> > ◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
> > ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> > Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 12 pixels on
> > the bottom. Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by
> > 0.200 pixels on the right. Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 12 pixels on the bottom. Another exception
> > was thrown:    A RenderFlex overflowed by 0.200 pixels on the right.
> > Another    exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 12 pixels
> > on the    bottom. Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex
> > overflowed by
> > 0.200 pixels on the right. Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 12 pixels on the bottom. Performing hot
> > reload...    Reloaded 1 of 1166 libraries in 4,534ms. Performing hot
> > reload...    Reloaded 1 of 1166 libraries in 3,199ms. ══╡ EXCEPTION
> > CAUGHT BY    RENDERING LIBRARY
> > ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ The
> > following assertion was thrown during layout: A RenderFlex overflowed
> > by 0.200 pixels on the right. The relevant error-causing widget was:
> > Row
> > Row:file:///E:/work/nabaa_mobile-main/lib/ui/screens/home/widgets/bottom_home_page/home.dart:140:27
> > To inspect this widget in Flutter DevTools, visit:
> > http://127.0.0.1:9101/#/inspector?uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A56940%2FUjrL2FntShg%3D%2F&inspectorRef=inspector-2705
> > The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.horizontal. The
> > edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the
> > rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually
> > caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex. Consider
> > applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the
> > children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead
> > of being sized to their natural size. This is considered an error
> > condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be
> > seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space,
> > consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the
> > flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a
> > ListView. The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#4f67e
> > relayoutBoundary=up1 OVERFLOWING: creator: Row ← Column ← Padding ←
> > DefaultTextStyle ← AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ←
> > _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#c9285 ink renderer] ← NotificationListener ← CustomPaint ←
> > _ShapeBorderPaint ← PhysicalShape ← _MaterialInterior ← Material ← ⋯ parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use
> > size) constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=135.2, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
> > size: Size(135.2, 40.0) direction: horizontal mainAxisAlignment:
> > start mainAxisSize: max crossAxisAlignment: center textDirection: ltr
> > verticalDirection: down
> > ◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
> > ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> > Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 12 pixels on
> > the bottom.
>
> ========================================================================

**the code is**

```
 GridView.count(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                mainAxisSpacing: 4,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                crossAxisSpacing: 4.w,

                // padding: EdgeInsets.all(9),
                children: List.generate(4, (index) {
                  return Material(
                    // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      // side: ,

                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                    ),
                    type: MaterialType.button,
                    color: whiteColor,
                    elevation: 5,
                    // clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,

                    shadowColor: blackColor.withOpacity(0.5),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            CircleAvatar(
                              foregroundColor: blackColor,
                              child: ClipOval(
                                child:
                                    Image.asset('assets/images/meta-logo.png'),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 4.w),
                              child: Text(
                                "company_name".tr,
                                // textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                                style: Get.textTheme.headline3!
                                    .copyWith(color: faddenGreyColor),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Align(
                          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerStart,
                          heightFactor: 0.3.h,
                          child: Text(
                            "opportunity_title".tr,
                            style: Get.textTheme.headline4,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.calendar_today_outlined,
                              color: faddenGreyColor,
                              size: 13.sp,
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 2.w),
                              child: Text(
                                "date".tr,
                                style: Get.textTheme.headline3!.copyWith(
                                  color: faddenGreyColor,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.location_on_outlined,
                              color: faddenGreyColor,
                              size: 15.sp,
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 2.w),
                              child: Text(
                                "location".tr,
                                style: Get.textTheme.headline3!.copyWith(
                                  color: faddenGreyColor,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 2.h),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }),
              ),
```

Comment: can you print your result screen?

Comment: there is no update @RavindraS.Patil S. Patil

Answer (score 0):

-> Use Can  Use For This Code  SingleChildScrollView

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    class Data extends StatefulWidget {
      const Data({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
      @override
      _DataState createState() => _DataState();
    }
    
    class _DataState extends State<Data> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: GridView.count(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            mainAxisSpacing: 4,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            crossAxisSpacing: 4,
            // padding: EdgeInsets.all(9),
            children: List.generate(4, (index) {
              return Material(
                // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  // side: ,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                ),
                type: MaterialType.button,
                color: Colors.white,
                elevation: 5,
                // clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                shadowColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        CircleAvatar(
                          foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                          child: ClipOval(
                            child: Image.asset('assets/images/meta-logo.png'),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 4),
                          child: Text(
                            "company_name",
                            // textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                            style: TextStyle(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerStart,
                      child: Text(
                        "opportunity_title",
                        style: TextStyle(),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.calendar_today_outlined,
                          color: Colors.red,
                          size: 13,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 2),
                          child: Text(
                            "location",
                            style: TextStyle(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.location_on_outlined,
                          color: Colors.red,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 2),
                          child: Text(
                            "location",
                            style: TextStyle(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 2),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: the same issue @kk web

Answer (score 0):

Expanded all your widget in `Column`

```
GridView.count(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        mainAxisSpacing: 4,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        crossAxisSpacing: 4,

        // padding: EdgeInsets.all(9),
        children: List.generate(4, (index) {
          return Material(
            // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              // side: ,

              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
            ),
            type: MaterialType.button,

            elevation: 5,
            // clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
            color: Colors.white,

            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            child: ClipOval(
                              child: Image.asset('images/profile.png'),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 4),
                            child: Text(
                              "company_name",
                              // textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerStart,
                      heightFactor: 0.3,
                      child: Text(
                        "opportunity_title",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.calendar_today_outlined,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 2),
                            child: Text(
                              "date",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.location_on_outlined,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 2),
                            child: Text(
                              "location",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
```

output: [image]

Comment: i need to add padding above the material, nothing new with using Expanded. @Jahidul Islam

Comment: once i add padding the error exception appears

Comment: where you add padding

Comment: above material or column both are the same, @Jahidul Islam

Comment: updated my answer, removed some fixed length from icon and made them expanded and working fine

Comment: bro, if you change the value of Padding nothing will change!
@Jahidul Islam

Comment: i used padding and it's worked my machine, sorry to hear that

Comment: at least you tried to help me 3>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240137/discussion-between-jahidul-islam-and-winter).